# Настройка DATETIME() в MySQL для работы с Python

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, datetime

В Python есть некий стандарт (что не удивительно, конечно) для работы с датой. Например, если вывести `datetime.now()`, то это сразу будет видно.

Так вот, я хочу настроить MySQL так, чтобы в базу легко можно было добавлять дату из Python. Что я должен указать в качестве аргумента типа `DATETIME()` при создании таблицы, чтобы все было грамотно ?

Опыт работы с базами данных у меня очень мал...

Comment: какой модуль/библиотеку вы используете для работы с MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот работающий пример для SQLAlchemy (де-факто стандарт при работе с различными БД в Python):

MySQL create table:

```
mysql> create table dt(
    ->     id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ->     dt timestamp default current_timestamp
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
```

Python code:

```
import datetime
import sqlalchemy

db_url = 'mysql://testuser:password@mysql_server_hostname/db_name'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_url)
conn = engine.connect()

sql = 'INSERT INTO dt(dt) values(%s)'
rslt = conn.execute(sql, (datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11)))
rslt = conn.execute(sql, (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)))
conn.close()
```

Result:

```
mysql> select * from dt;
+----+---------------------+
| id | dt                  |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2016-11-11 11:11:11 |
|  3 | 2016-12-12 12:12:12 |
+----+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```